# How can I send a file via wi-fi between two pocket PCs?

Tags: windows-mobile, java-me, java

I have two Pocket PCs and I want write an application that be able to send a file via Wi-Fi, as you know the Pocket PC's OS is Windows-mobile.

Can I use J2SE ?(Because windows-mobile) or I must write J2ME Application?  Please kindly advise me, with a sample source code about that.

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A tutorial of setting up and using Wi-Fi peer-to-peer connections between Pocket PC](http://www.smartphonemag.com/cms/blogs/3/588#more588)

After that you just need to write a simple socket server and you should be good to go.

Below are a couple of JVMs that will run on Windows Mobile.

Mysaifu JVM
[Product page](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html)
Mysaifu JVM, according to the official product page, is a "Java Virtual Machine which runs on Windows Mobile. It is a free software under the GPLv2 (GNU Public License Version 2)."

Mysaifu JVM (Java Virtual Machine) will work with most Windows-based PDAs and PDA phones, including those that run on Windows Mobile 5.0, 6.0, Windows Mobile 2003 for Pocket PC, and Windows Mobile 2003 Second Edition for Pocket PC. The actual size of the files is quite small at just 5MB, but you'll need about 10MB of free space in order to complete the installation.

Ewe Launcher
[Company page](http://www.ewesoft.com/eve/index.html)
Ewe is actually a "programming system that allows you to write applications, using Java, which run exactly the same on desktop systems, on mobile systems, and even in a Web browser as an Applet." In this way, it's not exactly a free Java runtime environment (J2RE) for Windows Mobile, but there is a Ewe Launcher which seems to fulfill this need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP over WiFi. J2SE I dont think so.

You can use the .NET compact framework and C# which is very similar to Java
or you can use Java ME CDC from Sun.
Last time I checked they had a runtime for Windows Mobile.

For FTP code check out OpenNETCF (compact framework).

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at this area a few years ago now I did find a JVM called [Mysaifu](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html) and the author was very helpful with feature requests and bug fixes so you can code if you really want to in java using his jvm.

I think the easiest thing would be to use visual studio and c/c++. If you must use java you can use this Mysaifu as your JVM. It worked fine for me at the time.

Comment: You better look it up again then 


http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp#2



Key Features
 
Integration with 3rd party emulators and Windows Mobile devices
The new Java ME Platform SDK architecture allows integration of 3rd party emulators and devices. Java ME Platform SDK comes with Sun's Java runtime environment for Windows Mobile. A user can install this runtime on a Windows Mobile device or a Microsoft device emulator and experience all the on-device features of Java ME Platform SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/) tutorial. The examples is not java, but it could be useful.